# How can I make this command only be used by admins?

Tags: discord.js

this is a code a command to delete an x ​​number of messages who works perfectly, but how can I make only members with administrator permission use it?

[This is the code of the command](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/707261013656994911/711334380567658616/IMG_20200516_234730.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for the administrator permission, you can use

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You don't have the administrator permission!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if(!message.member.roles.cache.has('roleID')) return message.channel.send(`your message`)
```

Hope this helps!